# Run websocket onmessage in different thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, websocket, eventmachine, em-websocket

I am using websocket on a server as below. It responds to `onmessage` events, and are conditioned to do different tasks according to the message:

```
require "websocket-eventmachine-server"

WebSocket::EventMachine::Server.start(host: some_server_name, port: some_port) do |ws|
  # (A) Here, the current thread is the main thread
  ws.onmessage do |s|
    if foo
      # (B) Here, the current thread is the main thread
      ...
    else
      # (C) Here, the current thread is the main thread
      ...
    end 
  end
end
```

The thread where every `onmessage` event is executed (described as `B` and `C` above) is the same each time, and they are the same as the main thread (described as `A` above).

I want to execute code in `B` in a separate thread as `C`. One way to do that is to put the operations in `B` and `C` within a new thread as below:

```
WebSocket::EventMachine::Server.start(host: some_server_name, port: some_port) do |ws|
  # (A) Here, the current thread is the main thread
  ws.onmessage do |s|
    if foo
      # (B) Here, the current thread will be created each time.
      Thread.new{...}
    else
      # (C) Here, the current thread will be created each time.
      Thread.new{...}
    end
  end
end
```

but creating a new thread every time an event occurs seems to be heavy, and is making the response slow. So, I want one thread to be shared among all `onmessage` events processed in `B`, and another one to be shared among all events processed in `C`:

```
WebSocket::EventMachine::Server.start(host: some_server_name, port: some_port) do |ws|
  # (A) Here, the current thread is the main thread
  ws.onmessage do |s|
    if foo
      # (B) I want this part to be executed in a thread
      #     that does not change each time, but is different from the thread in C
      ...
    else
      # (C) I want this part to be executed in a thread
      #     that does not change each time, but is different from the thread in B
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

What would be a good way to do this? Or, is there a better structure to respond to websocket `onmessage` events in a mutually non-blocking way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EventMachine.defer` method to execute code in it's internal thread pool.

Comment: You didn't make it clear enough, but there is `WebSocket::EventMachine.defer` in addition to `EventMachine.defer`.

Answer (score -2):

You can make queue(s) of messages received, and make one thread by queue for execute
the traitment :

```
def do_foo(message)
   .... your code
end
def do_fee(message)
   .... your code
end

queueA= Queue.new
queueB= Queue.new
Thread.new { loop { do_foo(queueA.pop) } }
Thread.new { loop { do_fee(queueB.pop) } }
WebSocket::EventMachine::Server.start(host: some_server_name, port: some_port) do |ws|
  # (A) Here, the current thread is the main thread
  ws.onmessage do |s|
    if foo
       queueA.push(s)
    else
       queueB.push(s)
    end
  end
end
```

Warning !! if do_foo/fee need to send message on the websocket,  you should
call the 'if foo..' in a a EM.next_tick { if .. }.

Comment: How are `do_foo` and `do_fee` defined?